# 80s/90s movie featuring a samurai-looking alien villain with an Asian sun hat–shaped head

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The villain of this movie is a samurai-looking alien. This alien had a China-faced extension that came out of the forehead area. Also, its head was shaped like an Asian sun hat from *Mortal Kombat*. I have searched movie lists from the 1980s and 1990s with no luck. I have also tried to search images for the villain to get a clue.

What movie is this villain from?

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by "a china-faced extension"?

Comment: Anything else you could add would help. Setting? Who or what was the protagonist? Was it dubbed? Types of weapons used?

Comment: I really want to know what a _a china-faced extension_ is/looks like.

Comment: China-faced extension either means an extendable porcelain mask, and/or a face mask with asiatic features

Comment: It's not one of the villains from any of these movies is it? "Big Trouble in Little China" (a Carpenter classic featuring Raiden style hats on the villains, they  aren't aliens though), "Guyver" (Cult classic film with mutants, the lead villain in the first film has a large crested head), or could it be "Hellboy" (more recent film, villains are mostly Nazi'ish, but there are some samurai looking monsters with masks.)

Comment: *Liu Kang Wins!*

Answer (score 11):

The description of the villain reminds me of the antagonist of the 1991 Japanese live action film titled [Zeiram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeiram), who also appears in the 1994 anime prequel [Iria: Zeiram the Animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iria:_Zeiram_the_Animation).

He had a head shaped sort of like a Chinese straw hat (or [a Japanese kasa hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasa_(hat))), which had a white face on it which resembles [a mask from Noh theater](http://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/45501).

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even if this isn't the villain, nice find!

Comment: I think this has got to be the right answer. Reading the description, I immediately thought of Zeiram.